# UWP - Dependency property - UIPropertyMetada confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies, uwp

I`m moving my project from wpf to UWP and I don't understand how can I create Dependency property in UWP with CoerceValueCallback, like in WPF

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumFrequencyProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("MinimumFrequency", typeof(int), typeof(SpectrumAnalyzer), 
       new UIPropertyMetadata(20, OnMinimumFrequencyChanged, OnCoerceMinimumFrequency));
```

But as I understood there are no CoerceCallback in UWP. Or I`m not right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoerceValueCallback is not supported in UWP.

[PropertyMetadata in UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.propertymetadata.aspx) lives in the Windows.UI.Xaml namespace and has following constructors:

- `PropertyMetadata(Object)`
- `PropertyMetadata(Object, PropertyChangedCallback)`

[PropertyMetaData in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) lives in the System.Windows namespace, has 5 constructors. One of them with CoerceValueCallback: `PropertyMetadata(Object, PropertyChangedCallback, CoerceValueCallback)`

Comment: Yea. I understand, but how can I set coerce callback in uwp. if I need to get the moment, when value coercing? :D

Comment: You can't. You'll have to add extra logic to the regular callback handler.